# Dynamic Import .py Modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

My `main.py` needs to use functions from `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py` ...and so on, all of these `.py` have i functions called `samefunctionname()` implemented.

In The `main.py` I want to do `if`, `elif`,`elif`, `elif`...., `else` statement and decide from which `*.py` I want to `import` the `samefunctionname()`.

The `main.py` should be static, but it is easy to add file `zz.py` and be able to call its function from main.

i hope its understandable :)

Now in pseudocode

```
lines=readfile()
for line in lines:
    //import line[0].py
    call line[0].samefunction
    //deimport line[0].py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `importlib.import_module` to import something from a string (Python 3.4 or up):

```
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module("os")

print(repr(module))
# <module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py'>
```

Then you can call the function you want:

```
module.chdir(".")  # same as os.chdir(".")
```